# Changes in Get-AzureRmStorageAccount - AccountType missing

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell

I noticed that the `AccountType` property in the `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount` output is missing. This coincides with the introduction of the cool/hot storage. The property `Kind` got added and the `AccountType` dropped.

Any idea how I could get this information using PowerShell? In the Portal this information is still available. Kind of important to have this information in PowerShell objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new PS module version 1.4.0 onwards, you can get the same data from "Sku.Name" for each account. E.g.

---

PS C:\Users\xxxxxx> $Accounts = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount

**Earlier:**

PS C:\Users\xxxxxx> $Accounts[0].AccountType

StandardLRS

**Now:**
PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx> $Accounts[0].Sku.Name

StandardLRS

---

Hope this helps,

Sri